# How to access tokens stored in local storage?

Tags: authentication, local-storage, access-token

Suppose a user logs into my web app and my web app produces a access token and stores it in local storage in client side. But when user enters into other webpage in the same domain, How can I get the access token in local storage along with the request so that the server knows that user is already authenticated?

Comment: What framework or language are you using for tge task?

Comment: I am using Node JS. And JWT for creating tokens

Comment: And for front-end?

Comment: I am not using any framework for front end.

Comment: Then use JavaScript functions on page load. `localStorage.getItem` and `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: Suppose that a page is only accessible if I am logged in. Suppose that I had logged in. Now if I open that webpage in a new tab how will the server know I am logged in? Does the request also contains the token stored in local storage? If not, how I can make sure that the request comes along with token stored in local storage

Comment: Ohh sorry! Now I think I got it. Is this what you are saying? When page loads check for access token in local storage and send request to server using ajax. Am I right?

Comment: Yes u need to check everytime your application loads. And i would recommend reading up on jwt architecture

Answer (score 1):

To set `localStorage` data from response:

`localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.token);`

To get `localStorage` data:

`let authorizationToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");`